# VirtualHost's not acting as expected with subdomain

Tags: apache

Here is a simplification of my setup. I have a default VirtualHost with no ServerName or ServerAliases (000-default.conf in sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I have another one (stuff.joe.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/stuff/
ServerName stuff.joe.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In my mind, I think I have a pretty good idea of how this should work.

Accessing http://joe.com/ properly takes me to the default virtual host and points in the right place (/var/www/html/).

Accessing http://stuff.joe.com/index.html finds the secondary virtual host config and takes me to where I would expect it to go (/var/www/stuff/index.html).

However... accessing http://stuff.joe.com/, contrary to what I would think, matches up with the default virtual host and takes me to /var/www/html/

This seems odd. Am I missing something here? I would expect it to either catch the stuff.joe.com config or not in both cases. Why does it act differently in the two cases?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the DirectoryIndex directive on the secondary virtual host config and so it was falling back to the default virtual host.